# No rows returned by REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

I have the following expression that matches the string listed when I test it using Online Regex Tester (https://regex101.com/).

Expression:

```
^(?:[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}[a-z]{1}\([0-9]{1,3}\-[0-9]{1,3}\))\+\s?(?:[A-Z]{2}\((?:[0-9]{1,3}((?:\-[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s?\,\s?)?))?)+\)(?:\s?\+\s?)?)*$
```

String Input:

`ATL107j(1-132)+XD(133-156)+SP(157-288)+XD(289-432)`

If I use:

`SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE([String Input], [Expression])`

I get no rows.  I am not sure what is wrong with the expression as it relates to REGEXP_LIKE.  I am using **Oracle 11gR2**.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: when i tried the expression with input on the test site, i get no match..perhaps you missed something?

Comment: Same as above... no match!

Comment: Oops. Sorry.  Copied the incorrect expression.  Here is the correct one that should work with this string input on the test site.  Thanks for checking it out: ^(?:[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}[a-z]{1}\([0-9]{1,3}\-[0-9]{1,3}\))\+\s?(?:[A-Z]{2}\((?:[0-9]{1,3}((?:\-[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s?\,\s?)?))?)+\)(?:\s?\+\s?)?)*$

Comment: still no match...what about the input?

Comment: I see what is happening.  When I paste my expression here, it changes it.

Comment: [CODE] ^(?:[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}[a-z]{1}\([0-9]{1,3}\-[0-9]{1,3}\))\+\s?(?:[A-Z]{2}\((?:[0-9]{1,3}((?:\-[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s?\,\s?)?))?)+\)(?:\s?\+\s?)?)*$ [/CODE]

Comment: ^(?:[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}[a-z]{1}\([0-9]{1,3}\-[0-9]{1,3}\))\+\s?(?:[A-Z]{2}\((?:[0-9]{1,3}((?:\-[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s?\,\s?)?))?)+\)(?:\s?\+\s?)?)*$

I indented the expression 4 spaces.

Comment: Hmmm.  Even indent didn't work!  Not sure how to paste the expression here without it being altered!

Comment: what you want to do is edit your initial post and do the following: delete your initial regex, paste new regex, select your regex in full and then click the { }  on the formatting options.

Comment: To show "code" in a comment (not in a Question or an Answer), use the back-single-quote (on most keyboards it's in the upper-left corner), the symbol ` before and after your code.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I did what cableload suggested and modified the post.  I believe the expression is intact now.

Comment: After some research I found that dropping the capture group from the expression does the trick for REGEXP_LIKE.  I am not sure if there is a way to tell Oracle to ignore capture groups, but I am able to run it in Oracle now.  Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Ha! I guess we were experimenting at the same time (see my Answer). Oracle DOES support "capture groups" - the syntax only requires the use of parentheses, there is no ?: right after the (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `?:` right after an open parenthesis, as in `(?: ... )`   ?  That is not in the Oracle flavor of regex; if you remove all the ?: pairs, the query will return one row. In Oracle, the ?: are taken literally:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual where regexp_like('?:', '(?:)');

         1
----------
         1
1 row selected.
```

You must be using a regular expression feature from a different flavor, not supported by Oracle.

Comment: Thanks mathguy.  I found the same thing.  Capture groups don't seem to be supported by Oracle.  Thanks again.

Comment: Actually yes, Oracle does support capture groups, just with a different syntax. `select regexp_substr('abc-02-e', '^([a-z]+)-(\d+)-.*$', 1, 1, null, 2) from dual;` returns the second capture group, '02'  (see the documentation for regexp; here the last argument, 2, indicates which capture group should be returned).

Comment: Ah!  Awesome,  Thanks again!